# Traefik Ingress (Kubernetes) not receiving letsencrypt certificates

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, traefik-ingress

I've configured Traefik (helm chart) with let'sencrypt ACME, but I'm not receiving any certificates. The Traefik Ingress is exposed on port 80 and 443 to the internet.

traefik.toml

```
logLevel = "INFO"
InsecureSkipVerify = true
defaultEntryPoints = ["http","https"]
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
  compress = true
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
  compress = true
    [entryPoints.https.tls]
      [[entryPoints.https.tls.certificates]]
      CertFile = "/ssl/tls.crt"
      KeyFile = "/ssl/tls.key"
[kubernetes]
[acme]
email = "email@email.com"
storage = "/acme/acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
onHostRule = true
caServer = "https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
acmeLogging = true
  [acme.httpChallenge]
  entryPoint = "http"
[web]
address = ":8080"
```

Ingress with Traefik as IngressClass

```
{
  "kind": "Ingress",
  "apiVersion": "extensions/v1beta1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "domain",
    "namespace": "reverse-proxy",
    "selfLink": "/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/reverse-proxy/ingresses/domain",
    "uid": "550cdedc-ba77-11e8-8657-00155d00021a",
    "resourceVersion": "6393921",
    "generation": 5,
    "creationTimestamp": "2018-09-17T12:43:52Z",
    "annotations": {
      "ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect": "true",
      "kubernetes.io/ingress.class": "traefik"
    }
  },
  "spec": {
    "tls": [
      {
        "hosts": [
          "domain.com"
        ],
        "secretName": "cert" // without is also not working
      }
    ],
    "rules": [
      {
        "host": "domain.com",
        "http": {
          "paths": [
            {
              "backend": {
                "serviceName": "domain",
                "servicePort": 443
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "host": "www.domain.com",
        "http": {
          "paths": [
            {
              "backend": {
                "serviceName": "www-domain",
                "servicePort": 443
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "status": {
    "loadBalancer": {}
  }
}
```

I've tried to use both http-01 and tls-sni-01 challenge. dns-01 is no option, because my DNS provider doesn't have an API.

Answer (score 2):

How are you injecting the letsencrypt config to your traefik Ingress service/daemonset?

Traefik doesn't officially have letsencrypt on Kubernetes Ingress docs. But this is a [good guide](https://medium.com/@carlosedp/multiple-traefik-ingresses-with-letsencrypt-https-certificates-on-kubernetes-b590550280cf). Look for "External Traefik ingress controller" and you need a kv backend to store your certs.

You can also try [cert-manager](https://cert-manager.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) which works with Traefik.

Comment: Cert-manager works fine with Traefik and is the recommended solution.

Comment: Cool, added it to the answer. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

The built-in ACME support for Traefik is not recommended for use on Kubernetes at this time as setting up failover/redundancy becomes difficult. Cert-manager, as mentioned by Rico, is a better solution and is the one recommended by the Traefik team currently :)