# Traefik LetsEncrypt certificate in Helm Ingress

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, lets-encrypt

I'm missing some form of configuration/knowledge when configuring an ingress through Helm for a chart.

I want to enable TLS for an existing chart which has the following values:

```
ingress:
  enabled: false
  annotations: {}
    # kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    # kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
  path: /
  hosts:
    - chart-example.local
  tls: []
  #  - secretName: chart-example-tls
  #    hosts:
  #      - chart-example.local
```

From what I've read on the Traefik docs you can't use LetsEncrypt certificates in k8s secrets:

> Only TLS certificates provided by users can be stored in Kubernetes Secrets. Let's Encrypt certificates cannot be managed in Kubernets Secrets yet.

What are my options here, do I overwrite the ingress and potentially mess with future helm upgrades or is annotations the way to go? If so an example would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Only TLS certificates provided by users can be stored in Kubernetes
> Secrets. Let's Encrypt certificates cannot be managed in Kubernets
> Secrets yet.

It was discussed few times here, on stack. Maybe it will help you.

The most recommended solution is to use [cert-manager](https://cert-manager.io/docs/) instead of `LetsEncrypt`.

**1.** [Traefik Ingress (Kubernetes) not receiving letsencrypt certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52376384/9929015)

**2.** [Let's Encrypt on Traefik with Helm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52375014/9929015)

Also here is [How to easily(ish!) get SSL/TLS configured for your web hosting needs using Traefik and cert-manager on Kubernetes](https://medium.com/@alexgued3s/how-to-easily-ish-471307f276a9) article for you that shows everything is in details.

Comment: Thanks, I went down the route of cert-manager and it seems to work really well.